# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have a Next.js component that's throwing an 'Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.' It mentions that this error can occur when a component repetitively calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React restricts the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

```js
"use client";
import fakeData from "../MOCK_DATA.json";
import { useTable } from "react-table";
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = React.useMemo(() => fakeData, []);
  const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: "ID",
      accessor: "id",
    },
    {
      Header: "Primeiro Nome",
      accessor: "first_name",
    },
    {
      Header: "Último Nome",
      accessor: "last_name",
    },
    {
      Header: "Email",
      accessor: "email",
    },
    {
      Header: "Genero",
      accessor: "gender",
    },
    {
      Header: "IP Address",
      accessor: "ip_address",
    },
  ]);

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({ columns, data });

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

. I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Looks like you need to add a dependency array to `columns`.  It's currently being recalculated on every render, which is likely being triggered by `useTable`.  Also, don't need to memoize `fakeData`.  Try that and let me know.